# Material-UI React Table throwing border off on render

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am looking for a quick fix for this. It seems like whenever I render from a dataset returned from an API call in a Material-UI.com table (no additions in terms of styling that would throw it off) it gives me what looks like a border but margin or padded to the right. Any experience with this please let me know. Picture showing this below:

[image]

Code for table here:

```
<Table
                            selectable={false}
                            fixedHeader={true}
                            fixedFooter={false}
                            style={{
                                backgroundColor: Colors.purple
                            }}>
                            <TableHeader
                                enableSelectAll={false}
                                displaySelectAll={false}
                                adjustForCheckbox={false}>
                                <TableRow displayBorder={false}>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        style={{
                                            Colors.white
                                        }}>
                                        COLUMN HEADER
                                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        style={{
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            width: 100
                                        }}>
                                        COLUMN HEADER
                                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        style={{
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            width: 100
                                        }}>
                                        COLUMN HEADER
                                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHeader>
                            <TableBody
                                displayRowCheckbox={false}
                                stripedRows={true}
                                showRowHover={true}>
                                {this.state.ARRAY.map(function(row, index) {
                                    if (moment(row.START_OF_QUARTER).isSame(quarterSelected)) {
                                        return (
                                            <TableRow style={{color: Color.white}} key={index} displayBorder={false}>
                                                <TableRowColumn>
                                                    {row.User}
                                                </TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn
                                                    style={{width: 100}}>
                                                    ${row.DATA}
                                                </TableRowColumn>
                                                <TableRowColumn
                                                    style={{width: 100}}>
                                                    {row.DATA}
                                                </TableRowColumn>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        );
                                    }
                                })}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
```